# Using .find() on a pd.dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following df:

```
data = {'Org':  ['<a href="/00xO" target="_blank">Chocolate</a>'],
        'Owner': ['Charlie']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

and when I apply the lamba function below instead of giving me 'Chocolate' it's returning  0.

```
df['Correct Org']=df['Org'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find(">"):st.find("<")])
```

I've tried adding 'str' as follows:

```
df['Correct Org']=df['Org'].str.apply(lambda st: st[st.find(">")+1:st.find("<")])
```

& get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting None returned because `df['Org'][0].find(">")` returns 31 but `df['Org'][0].find("<")` returns 0. So it's not clear what `st[st.find(">"):st.find("<")` means. You can use [`bs4.BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create a soup object and get the text inside `a` directly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df['Org'] = df['Org'].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x).text)
```

Output:

```
         Org    Owner
0  Chocolate  Charlie
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for parsing html tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df['Correct Org']=df['Org'].apply(lambda st: ','.join(BeautifulSoup(st, features="lxml").findAll(text=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If *you don't want to use BeautifulSoup*, I wrote a simple function for you.

### A FUNCTION FOR GETTING THE LINK TEXT

```py
def getOrg(link):
    link = str(link)
    link = link[link.find('>'):link.find("</")]
    return link.replace(link[0], '')
```

### FOR EXAMPLE

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Org':  ['<a href="/00xO" target="_blank">Chocolate</a>'],
        'Owner': ['Charlie']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Function Call
getOrg(df['Org'])
```

**OUTPUT**

> Chocolate